# How to send array of ids correctly in express

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, express

I have array of ids like the follows:

```
var arr = [1, 23, 6];
```

I need to send this array to a server, parse it, and remove the ids from a mongoose db. For my backend I'm using nodejs express. So I need your advise how should I send the array by using jQuery and how should I parse it on a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, follow this instructions and you are good:

first of all, lets create our node server, I'm using the Express module to define the HTTP server:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();


app.listen(8080);

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.send(html);
});

app.post('/deleteIds', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.arr[0]);
    res.json({ success: true });
});
```

The server '/' request returns an HTML page that will create an jQuery Ajax request, Here is the HTML file content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/deleteIds',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                arr: [ 1, 2, 3]
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the Ajax request in the html file sent as a POST request with an array as the data, The `/deleteIds` express path POST function in the server listens to that and takes the array using `req.body.arr`, note that I'm using `app.use(express.bodyParser());`, without this line we will not be able to get the body content from the POST request.

This is it.. I hope this is helping understand Node + Ajax requests using express, from this point you can run on the `arr` and do what you want with the data.

Answer (score 9):

Basically a comment on @udidu's good answer, but I want markdown formatting so I'll post it as an answer. Here's some minor improvement suggestions:

- Omit everything but the path from the url "/deleteIds" on the javascript side so it will work no matter how it is served.
- You can send the array as a JSON string without an object wrapper

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: '/deleteIds',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]),
      contentType: "application/json",
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  ```
- In the server, the array will be available as just `req.body`
- As per REST conventions, this should be using the HTTP `DELETE` method (I've changed the jquery. You will also need to change the express code to do `app.del` instead of `app.post`).

Comment: it is replaced with {} to me :(

Comment: Most important settings that made my use case work: 

- data: JSON.stringify(…)
- processData: false
- contentType: "application/json"

Comment: What you describe as 'sending the array without an object wrapper' is incorrect- you are sending a serialized version of the array as a string. You should leave that work to jQuery, or explain why you are overriding its serialization.

Comment: Because as I read the jquery `$.ajax` docs, the default serialization is not JSON: "By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false."

Comment: @nick, try JSON.parse(data)